# Max Rotation in Createjs (adobe animate cc)

Tags: javascript, createjs, animate-cc

Im making a car parking project with Adobe Animate CC (HTML5).
I have into my canvas a Car and its Wheels.With the command below i can rotate the wheels left or right by pressing keyboard arrows.

```
document.onkeydown = keyHandler.bind(this);
function keyHandler(event) {

var e = event||window.event;
//left
if(e.keyCode == 37) {
    this.car.wheels3.rotation-=2;
```

But i want to make it to rotate in a certain rotation ratio , like a real wheel of a car rotates.I think i have to make a method but i dont know how to use rotate property with the method i want to create.Any thought/ help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need wheel animation actually:

```
createjs.Tween.get(car.wheel,{loop:true,override:true}).to({rotation:"360"}, 1000);
//or
createjs.Tween.get(car.wheel,{loop:true,override:true}).to({rotation:"-360"}, 1000);
```

**Update, based on new circumstances:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example</title>
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<script>
function init() 
{
    var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(24);  //set some FPS
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage); //set autiomatic refresh

    //let's draw something like wheels, with registration point somewhere in the middle :)
    var wheels=new createjs.Shape();
    wheels.graphics.beginFill("#CCCCCC").drawRect(-100,0,20,50);
    wheels.graphics.beginFill("#CCCCCC").drawRect(-100,15,200,20);
    wheels.graphics.beginFill("#CCCCCC").drawRect(100,0,20,50);
    stage.addChild(wheels);


    wheels.x=200;
    wheels.y=100;


    document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown );

    var wheelsInitialRotation=wheels.rotation; //save whells initial rotation
    var maximumAngleForRotation=20; //set maximum angle

    function onKeyDown(e)
    {
        var amount;
        e = e || window.event;

        switch(e.keyCode)
        {
            //right
            case 39:
                amount=2;
                break;
            //left
            case 37:
                amount=-2;
                break;
            //all other
            default:
                amount=0;

        }

        //check is new angle is not more or less then allowed :)
        if(!(wheels.rotation+amount>wheelsInitialRotation+maximumAngleForRotation || wheels.rotation+amount<wheelsInitialRotation-maximumAngleForRotation))
        {
            wheels.rotation+=amount;
        }



    }


}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: createjs.Tween.get means that a class is being created??

Comment: TweenJS is the part of the CreateJS library, it's used for the animations, check here: http://www.createjs.com/tweenjs

Comment: The method `get` means a new tween instance is returned, with the properties you specified (in the case of the @gMirian code, `loop` and `override`).

Comment: @gMirian Maybe you didnt understand exactly what i wanna do.Check this picture out to see what i want to do : http://imgur.com/a/PdmvZ

Comment: @Β_origin, please, check new example, I edited the post, just copy/paste this code and check. :)

Comment: @gMirian I want to hug you ! Really thanks. I have some questions altough..Why if statement has two parenthesis ? And second question is why in wheelsInitialRotation-maximumAngleForRotation there is (-) instead of (+) ?Btw im using amount -=2 or amount +=2 it gives more confidence controling the wheels than amount =-2 .

Comment: @Β_origin "if" tests angle maximum and minimum, not to exceed in our case 20 left or right, it's just a quick code, only for the example, you can set there your logic prefer :), same with += or -=, it's developers preferences how to write the code, in which manner or logic, I'm glad that this example helped you to move forward :)

Comment: @gMirian I cant understand why you used 2 parenthesis for the IF statement, i have seen it only with one like that for example: if (that > this ) { code here

Comment: @gMirian btw now , how can i make it to move to the direction of the wheels?atan2 , math.pi or ?